# Циклический список для представления людей

Tags: c++, указатели, списки

Только начал разбираться со списками. Один момент в упор не понимаю. В книге Седжвика "Алгоритмы на С++" есть такой пример создания циклического списка для представления людей, расставленных в круг:

```
struct node {
    int item;
    node *next;

    node(int x, node *t){
        item = x;
        next = t;
    }
};

int main() {
    typedef node *link;
    link t = new node(1, 0);
    t->next = t;    
    link x = t;

    for (int i = 2; i < 5; i++)
        x = (x->next = new node(i, t));

    while (x != x->next){
        for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
            x = x->next;
        x->next = x->next->next;
    }

    cout << x->item << endl;

    delete t;   
    return 0;
}
```

Что делает этот блок:

```
link t = new node(1, 0);
t->next = t;
link x = t;
```

*1 строка:* создается указатель на экземпляр класса `node`, инициализируются его поля и выделяется память;

*2 строка:* аналогично `(*t).next = t;` В классе `node` есть поле `next` - указатель на `node`, которому присваивается `t` - указатель на экземпляра класса `node`? Можете объяснить, зачем это делается?

*3 строка:* аналогична строке `link x = new node(1, 0);` - первой строке?

P.S. И что означает `x->next = x->next->next;`? Следующему элементу в списке присваивается значение, хранящееся после следующего элемента списка:

`(*x).next = (*(*x).next)).next;`

Comment: next в структуре node это указатель на следующую такую структуру в цепочке (а не на int). Указатель это по сути адрес блока памяти где лежит структура. зачем делают t->next=t сказать сложно. надо внимательно смотреть если проверки дальнейшие. по сути они этим говорят что следующей за структурой t в цепочке идет она сама, что странно. 3-я строка абослютно не аналогична. она память не выделяет и не создает структур. это node *x=t; t как мы помним адрес структуры, вот этот адрес копируется еще и в x

Comment: Точно, ошибся, `int` заменил на `node`

Comment: @dmitrykozyr Там же в книге должны быть какие-то слова, говорящие о том, что эта функция делает. Почему вы спрашиваете здесь вместо того, чтобы обратиться к книге?

Comment: Спасибо за ответы, теперь более понятно. В книге это несколько раз перечитал, но только еще больше вопросов появилось)

Comment: Да, области памяти и указатели очень простая, но сложно объяснимая вещь. Плюс автор книги явно запутывает объявляя `link` по сути как синоним `node *`. Предлагаю при чтении этого кода заменить все слова `link` конструкцией `node *` может легче понимать будет ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вы сами написали, создается кольцевой список. А это означает, что последний элемент списка указывает на первый элемент списка.
Так сказать, все встали в круг и взялись за руки.:)

В этих предложениях

```
link t = new node(1, 0);
t->next = t;
```

создается первый элемент списка

```
link t = new node(1, 0);
```

который указывает сам на себя

```
t->next = t;
```

Затем в цикле создаются еще три элемента

```
link x = t;
for (int i = 2; i < 5; i++)
    x = (x->next = new node(i, t));
```

Каждый раз при добавлении нового элемента его поле `next` указывает на первый элемент

```
new node(i, t)
```

Указатель этого созданного элемента присваивается полю `next` предыдущего элемента, а переменная `x` получает значение созданного указателя.

Можно вставить отладочную печать

```
#include <iostream>

struct node 
{
    int item;
    node *next;

    node(int x, node *t){
        item = x;
        next = t;
    }
};

int main()
{
    typedef node *link;

    link t = new node( 1, 0 );
    t->next = t;    
    link x = t;

    for ( int i = 2; i < 5; i++ )
    {
        x = ( x->next = new node( i, t) );
    }        

    do
    {
        x = x->next;
        std::cout << "current: " << ( void * )x 
                  << ", value: " << x->item
                  << ", next: " << ( void * )x->next
                  << std::endl;
    } while ( x->next != t );

    return 0;
}
```

И получить примерно следующий вывод на консоль

```
current: 0x9cc570, value: 1, next: 0x9cc590
current: 0x9cc590, value: 2, next: 0x9cbda0
current: 0x9cbda0, value: 3, next: 0x9cbdc0
current: 0x9cbdc0, value: 4, next: 0x9cc570
```

Как видно, последний элемент в списке указывает на первый элемент в списке, который имеет адрес `0x9cc570`

В этой тестовой программе цикл `do-while` начинается с предложения

```
x = x->next;
```

потому что перед этим в другом цикле при создании элементов `x` - это указатель последнего созданного элемента и его поле `next` указывает на первый элемент списка. Потому данное предложение при первой итерации цикла как раз и переходит на первый элемент списка.

Экспериментируйте с программой из книги и смотрите, что получается!

Comment: Спасибо, теперь все намного понятней, буду экспериментировать)

Comment: @dmitrykozyr Не за что. Спрашивайте еще.:)

Answer (score 1):

Если записать этот код нормально, то будет

```
node* t = new node(1, nullptr); // создаем новый элемент с типом node,
// в его конструктор передаем 1 (поле item) и нулевой указатель (поле next)
t->next = t; // делаем так чтобы поле next указывало на самого себя
```

Мы не можем написать `node* t = new node(1, t);`, потому что в момент вызова конструктора переменная `t` еще не заполнена.